# IIS 7.X dual support for 32 bits and 64 bits applications

Tags: iis-7, 32bit-64bit

*Here is a fact:
Microsoft Internet Information Server 6.0, imposes deployment restrictions on 32-bit and 64-bit applications. Specifically, IIS 6.0 can either support 32-bit applications or it can support 64-bit applications, but a single IIS instance cannot simultaneously support 32-bit and 64-bit application.*

**The question: can a single instance of IIS 7.0 (7.x) simultaneously support 32-bit and 64-bit applications?**

Answer (score 3):

In IIS7, there is an Advanced Setting for each Application Pool called **Enable 32-Bit Applications**.  So as long as they are separate Applications using separate App Pools, the answer is **yes**.

You can associate an entire Web Site with an App Pool (in Advanced Settings of the Web Site), or you can add a path-specific Application to a Web Site (so one Web Site could actually use multiple App Pools).